# Java: No Such File Or Directory (Using Scanner Class)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java.util.scanner, readfile, java-io

I'm trying to read from a file using the Scanner and File class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class TextFileReaderV1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    { 

        String token = "";
        File fileName = new File("data1.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);

        while( inFile.hasNext() )
        {
            token = inFile.next( );  
            System.out.println(token); 
        }
        inFile.close();           

     }
}
```

However, it is saying, "no such file or directory". and giving me the "java.io.FileNotFoundException"

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and the file is in the current directory I am working in: src/data1.txt -> next to GetFile.java (current code)

Full Error Message:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: data1.txt (No such file or directory)  

  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)  
  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)  
  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)  
  at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)  
  at GetFile.main(GetFile.java:19)
```

**Edit: ** It has been solved!! The run configuration was set to the project directory, not the src one, so I implicitly added it in the argument:

```
File fileName = new File("src/data1.txt");
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: What is the current working directory set to in your Run Configuration?

Comment: Line 19 causes the error and the current directory is Documents/Code/Java/Files/FileHandling (Project Name). Within that directory, there are the .idea, out, and src directories as well and I'm running src/GetFile.java @Code-Apprentice

Comment: It's been fixed! Thanks @Code-Apprentice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The run configuration was set to the project directory, not the src one, so I implicitly added it in the argument:

```
File fileName = new File("src/data1.txt");
```

Comment: It is typically a good idea to keep data files separate from source files.

Comment: I suggest learning how to specify the file to open as a command line argument. This makes your program much more flexible.

Answer (score -1):

Try entering the full path of the file.  If that works, you can either be done at that point or look into relative file paths.